# How to search for a pattern in text files in linux

Tags: bash

I have a large text and i need to filter out data matching an expression. Please help me with the commands which can be used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hello you can use commands like `grep` and `awk` to filter out data matching a pattern.

Syntax for `grep`

```
grep [options] pattern [files]
```

Syntax for `awk`

```
awk options 'selection _criteria {action }' input-file > output-file
```

For more clarification please visit the sites:

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/grep-command-in-unixlinux/

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/awk-command-unixlinux-examples/